# How can I make Rules react to `User has logged in` when user logs in through CAS?

Tags: 7, rules, users

I want to execute some php code when users log in, so I'm experimenting with the `Rules` module. I have it configured to fire a function of mine when a user logs in and it works fine, but it only works if the user logs in through Drupal. I am using CAS to authenticate users (thanks to the [CAS](http://drupal.org/project/cas) module) and if a user logs in with CAS, the function never gets called. Is there any way to solve this?

Here is the function which is successfully called when a user logs in through Drupal:

**myModuleName.rules.inc**

```
function myModuleName_rules_action_info () {
    return array(
        'hello_rules_world' => array(
            'label' => "Print Hello World to error.log"
        )
    );
}

function hello_rules_world () {
    error_log("Hello Rules World!");
}
```

And here is a screenshot of the configuration:

[image]

**UPDATE:** I ended up using `hook_user_login`, which detects all logins without problem:

**myModuleName.module**

```
function myModuleName_user_login (&$edit, $account) {
    my_user_login_function($account);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `hook_user_login`, which detects all logins without problem:

```
myModuleName.module

function myModuleName_user_login (&$edit, $account) {
    my_user_login_function($account);
}
```